# Javascript accessing variable

Tags: javascript, variables, scope

I am using the folowing code (located in file swipe.js):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.ui-slider-handle').live('touchstart', function(){
        // When user touches the slider handle, temporarily unbind the page turn handlers
        doUnbind();
    });

$('.ui-slider-handle').live('mousedown', function(){
    // When user touches the slider handle, temporarily unbind the page turn handlers
    doUnbind();
    });

$('.ui-slider-handle').live('touchend', function(){
    //When the user let's go of the handle, rebind the controls for page turn
    // Put in a slight delay so that the rebind does not happen until after the swipe has been triggered
    setTimeout( function() {doBind();}, 100 );
});

$('.ui-slider-handle').live('mouseup', function(){
    //When the user let's go of the handle, rebind the controls for page turn
    // Put in a slight delay so that the rebind does not happen until after the swipe has been triggered
    setTimeout( function() {doBind();}, 100 );
});

// Set the initial window (assuming it will always be #1
window.now = 1;

//get an Array of all of the pages and count
windowMax = $('div[data-role="page"]').length;

doBind();
});
// Functions for binding swipe events to named handlers
function doBind() {
    $('div[data-role="page"]').live("swipeleft", turnPage);
    $('div[data-role="page"]').live("swiperight", turnPageBack);
    }

function doUnbind() {
    $('div[data-role="page"]').die("swipeleft", turnPage);
    $('div[data-role="page"]').die("swiperight", turnPageBack);
    }

// Named handlers for binding page turn controls
function turnPage(){
    // Check to see if we are already at the highest numbers page
    if (window.now < windowMax) {
    window.now++
    $.mobile.changePage("#page"+window.now, {transition: window.localStorage.getItem("transitionsSettings")}, false, true);
}
else
            {
                window.now= window.now-2;
                $.mobile.changePage("#page"+window.now, {transition: window.localStorage.getItem("transitionsSettings")}, false, true);
}
}

function turnPageBack(){
    // Check to see if we are already at the lowest numbered page
    if (window.now != 1) {
    window.now--;
    $.mobile.changePage("#page"+window.now, {transition: window.localStorage.getItem("transitionsSettings"), reverse: "true"}, true, true);
}
else
            {
                window.now = window.now+2;
                $.mobile.changePage("#page"+window.now, {transition: window.localStorage.getItem("transitionsSettings"), reverse: "true"}, true, true);
}
}
```

I also have another file named loadFeed.js. They are both loaded inside index.html by this order:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/swipe.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/loadFeed.js"></script>
```

And here is the loadFeed.js file:

```
google.load("feeds", "1");
alert(window.now);
switch(now)
{
case 1:
    var link = "http://www.zive.sk/rss/sc-47/default.aspx";
    var listviewID = "feedZive";
    break;
case 2:
    var link = "http://mobilmania.azet.sk/rss/sc-47/default.aspx";
    var listviewID = "feedMobil";
    break;
case 3: 
    var link = "http://www.automoto.sk/rss";
    var listviewID = "feedAuto";
    break;
}
alert(link);
alert(listviewID);
alert("#"+listviewID);

function initialize() {
    var feed = new google.feeds.Feed(link);
    feed.setNumEntries(window.localStorage.getItem("entriesNumber"));
    feed.load(function(result) {
        if (!result.error) {
            var feedlist = document.getElementById(listviewID);
            for (var i = 0; i < result.feed.entries.length; i++) {
                var li = document.createElement("li");
                var entry = result.feed.entries[i];
                var A = document.createElement("A");
                A.setAttribute("href",entry.link);
                A.appendChild(document.createTextNode(entry.title));
                li.appendChild(A);
                feedlist.appendChild(li);
            }
            $("#"+listviewID).listview("refresh");
        }
    });
}
google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);
```

Is there any possible way to acces window.now variable in loadFeed.js?

Comment: Yes; just access it.  The `window` reference is global across all scripts on the page.

Comment: tried putting alert(window.now) inside loadFeed.js but I get undefined.

Comment: Note that you set `window.now` in a `$(document).ready`. So you need to wait in the other file as well until `ready` has occurred and the variable has been set (i.e. put the other reference to `now` also in a  ready function).

Comment: so I should just simply add $(document).ready(function() { at the beginning of my loadFeed.js? because if yes :) it is not working. Gona post whole loadFeed.js to question (edit it).

Comment: this whole thing is strange because I can change window.now from index.html by my <a onClick="window.now=window.now+1;"> but I cannont get its value.

Comment: @horin it depends on what order you are including your JS files and declaring document.ready on your main page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The `window` object is available everywhere. It's the mack daddy of globally scoped variables. You can use `window.now` in "loadFeed.js" or any javascript block or file.

In your case, you add the `now` property to the `window` object in a doc ready callback. So this isn't happening immediately. You shouldn't expect window.now to have a value right away. I would suggest either:

1) wrapping the code in "loadFeed.js" that accesses `window.now` in a doc ready callback like with much of the swipe.js code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //your code
    });
```

OR

2) In swipe.js, give `window.now` a value outside of the doc ready callback.

Comment: I can give it a value outside of the doc but I think it will then only change insinde doc ready callback, but I need it to change also outside the callback.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your comment... Just add `$(document).ready(function(){alert(window.now);});` to loadFeed.js and you'll see what I'm talking about.

Comment: I have done this and I have got the value by alert so it is working but after I click OK on alert my page looks like it is loading but loading never ends som my Feed never loads :)

Comment: You may need the rest of the code to be in the `$(document).ready(function(){ /* code here */ }` block, too (not just the alert). There may be other issues in the code, but you'll have to figure those out on your own :P

Comment: I have the whole code in $(document).ready(function(){ /* code here */ }. But ok,I will try to figure issues on my own.